# I am getting error when accessing variable on another module?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, global-variables

I have a module that is getting values from a datagrid and puts in the tags from each rows into the array of strings. I'm calling that array string on another module but i'm getting object not set to instance of an object. Why? What i'm trying to accomplish is combine all the tag into a array of strings or collection and be able to access it on another module.

```
'my main module
Public Class myMainModule
   Public Shared myArray() As String

   ......
   .......
   Public sub doSomething()
     Dim myArray As New List(Of String)
     For Each row As DataGridViewRow In mydatagrid.Rows
         If row.Cells("mycheckbox").Value = True Then
             myArray.Add(row.Tag)
         End If
     Next
  End Sub
End Class


'....then i'm calling it from another module:

Public Class myOtherModule
   Public sub doit()
     For Each value As String In myMainModule.myArray
         Debug.Print(value)
     Next
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You forgot the `Return myArray.ToArray()` at the end. `Option Strict Off` doesn't cause a compile error when you forget it. Always code with it On if you can.

Comment: @TyCobb where are you referring to at the end?

Comment: What i'm trying to accomplish is combine all the tag into a array of strings or collection and be able to access it on another module.

Comment: Get rid of the local variable `myArray` in doSomething... Also I would either 1 make it a function to return a list to you or 2 make a property you can access that gives you the list, don't use variables use properties as that's what they are for.

Comment: I agree with @Zaggler on using functions and properties. I would highly suggest you look into those and get a small working version together. Then you can take that version and head to codereview.stackexchange.com to get some insight into better structuring your code.

Comment: thanks @TyCobb but yes, i didn't set MyArray to the new array i created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your Array before you try to call it. Currently it is `Nothing`.

```
Public Class MyMainModule
    Public Shared MyArray() As String

    Public Shared Sub DoSomething()
        Dim myList As New List(Of String)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In mydatagrid.Rows
         If row.Cells("mycheckbox").Value = True Then
             myList.Add(row.Tag)
         End If
        Next

        MyArray = myList.ToArray()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyOtherModule
    Public Sub Foo()
        MyMainModule.DoSomething() 
        For Each value As String In MyMainModule.MyArray
            Debug.Print(value)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The other thing too is that you need to watch out for naming. I believe you got confused because you had a field called `myArray`, but also had a local variabled called `myArray`. You were working with the local variable that you newed up as `List(Of T)`, not an array.